# Get maximum value for a field, but only with respect to other documents with the same value in another field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have mongodb documents like this:

```
{'device':'A','value':12}
{'device':'A','value':13}
{'device':'A','value':14}
{'device':'B','value':4}
{'device':'B','value':5}
```

I would like to find

```
{'device':'A','value':14}
{'device':'B','value':5}
```

i.e. for each `device` (here `A` and `B`) the documents with the highest `value`.

What I am doing so far is to find all the distinct devices in one query and then get all the documents for each device individually sorted descending with a limit of 1. But this needs lots of queries.

Is there a way to do this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation operator with [**`$max`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) accumulator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$device",
    "value": {
      "$max": "$value"
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "_id": 0, "value": 1, "device": "$_id" }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qIBZy7pIRNo)